# Filling hole in limestone foundation wall with concrete

Tags: concrete, foundation, cement, engineering, digging

We have a garage built out of limestone bricks and sitting on a natural rock foundation. Recently, we dug our garage about 2 feet deeper by removing more of this rock. As a result, some of the rock which is now forming the foundation perimeter around the garage became loose and we ended with a couple of big holes (about 2 to 3 meters long (6 to 9 feet)) along one side. See picture for reference.

[image]

Notice the limestone wall sitting on the rock foundation and the poured concrete garage floor, which is hard to see here due to the dust on said floor.

[image]

[image]

- The question is, which kind of concrete should we use to fill in this
  hole?
- How should we mix it out of cement?
- What kind of additive should we use for this concrete?
- And what technique should we employ to fill in this hole?

Comment: What is the approximate volume of fill material needed? Without something in the pictures for scale, I'm having a hard time imagining. In the second photo, your 2m to 3m is the width along the wall from edge of photo to edge of photo?

Comment: Limestone is pretty soft. Most concrete expands a bit as it cures. I'm not sure that the two materials are compatible; you might need to look at something more like lime mortar.

Comment: I would use a flowfill material, basically a flowable grout.  You may need to do some forms and "pour" in stages.